# How in placeholder function of HTML block call library method?

Tags: laravel-livewire

Making rendering placeholder on Laravel / Livewire site as written here: https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/lazy#rendering-placeholder-html

I try to use my library method :

```
public function placeholder()
{
    return <<<'HTML'
    <div>
        ' . LibraryFacade::getProcessingCode() . '
    </div>
    HTML;
}
```

But that does not not and I see my php code on the text.

Which way is correct?

```
  "livewire/livewire": "^3.4.6",,
 "laravel/framework": "^10.45.1",
 "tailwindcss": "^3.4.1",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example on the Livewire website the *PHP nowdoc* syntax is used ([here](https://www.php.net/manual/it/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc) the reference).
If you have your own *class::method* to generate the placeholder you can simply return its output:

```
public function placeholder()
{
   return LibraryFacade::getProcessingCode();
}
```